# Remove the margin from far right gallery image

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

Please check this page: http://www.thamon.co.uk/e-store/

The 20px right margin float leaves an epty 20px space that can't be occupied by an image. The image jumps to the second row if I try to increase the .gallery-columns-3 width at least by 0.1%.

How can I delete the margin on the last image in gallery line?

```
* Default WordPress Gallery
     */
    .gallery {
        float: left;
        margin-bottom: 20px; 
    }
        .gallery br {
            display: none;
        }
        .gallery .gallery-item {
            margin: 0 20px 20px 0 !important;
            width: 100%;
            float: left;
            position: relative; 
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .gallery-columns-2 .gallery-item { 
        width: 50% !important; 
        }
        .gallery-columns-3 .gallery-item { 
            width: 31.2% !important;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
.gallery {
  margin: 0 -10px;
}
.gallery-item {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

That way you give the items an even margin all round, which still results in a gap of 20px, and you make the edges align with your content by making the wrapper 10px larger then the content area at each side.

(have a look at you HTML, `<dl`> does not seem really appropriate for a gallery item)

In your code, that would look something like this:

```
    .gallery {
        float: left;
        /* margin-bottom: 20px; */
        margin: 0 -10px;
    }
    /*.gallery br {
        display: none;
    }*/
    .gallery .gallery-item {
        /* margin: 0 20px 20px 0 !important; */
        margin: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        position: relative; 
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .gallery-columns-2 .gallery-item { 
        width: 50% !important; 
    }
    .gallery-columns-3 .gallery-item { 
        width: 31.2% !important;
```

Comment: PeterVR, thank you for your advice. <dl> is a preprogrammed code by the theme I am using. The code I uploaded is from styles.css from website admin page. I do not work on html directly so I am afraid I can't closely follow your advice to replace with something more appropriate, I simply don't know how to do it :)

Comment: Regarding your advice with the code you provided, could you please specify where exactly to put it with an example using my code above please?

Comment: Peter thanks for your advice, please check the link that I provided in description. All the photos are in one line now. However, 10px margins are both on the far left and far right. Was this supposed to be the outcome or some part of the code doesn't work?

Comment: If you inspect the code in something like Chrome Inspector, you can see that the `.gallery` margin is overwritten by `#gallery-2 {
 margin: auto;}`. Remove that line form your css and you should be fine...

Answer (score 0):

Use a pseudo selector

```
.gallery-item:last-child{margin-right:0;}
```

More info: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-child)

Comment: Thank you Nick, where exactly do I apply this code? I am a square zero beginner in css and html

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
.gallery-item:first-child + .gallery-item + .gallery-item
{
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

The above is the as using

```
.gallery-item:last-child
{
    margin-right:0px;
}
```

but `last-child` doesn't work on older versions of IE, while `first-child` does.

Comment: Howlin, thank you for your suggestion. Where exactly in the code I provided should I put your extracts? The code quotation I sent comes from styles.css

Comment: You can put it in  the bottom on the style.css file